# Installing ssd in 27 inch 2011 iMac

Tags: ssd, sata

I want to replace my SSD with the HDD inside my iMac and then move the HDD to the optical drive.

Is this possible?

I have read that I can install my SSD where the optical drive is, but I'm wondering if it will be a bottleneck for the speed of the ssd.  Or does this not matter?

Also, what about fans and cooling? Will the mac be able to handle it?  I have a kit from ifixit that has a sataIII cable. Does this matter?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "then move the HDD to the optical drive"? Do you mean to remove your optical drive and use the physical space for your HDD? If that is what you mean, there is no problem doing so and you should have enough air around it to dissipate any heat from the HDD. Speed won't be affected at all.

Comment: Thats exactly what I mean. Remove the optical and put the hdd there. My reason for that is that if I put the ssd in the optical bay, the connector available there will bottleneck the ssd?  Also i want to boot from the ssd. But for boot, does location matter?

Comment: I recommend booting from the first sata connector, but that's certainly no must. You can just swap the cables on the mobo. I'm not sure what you mean with a bottleneck... are you still using PATA connectors perhaps and connecting multiple devices on 1 port on the mobo?

Comment: Thanks. By first sata connector you mean where the HDD currently is? Why would this be better than putting in the optical bay?  Not sure what's back there. I haven't opened it yet, I want to wait until I know which one is going where.  My main concern was that putting the ssd in the optical bay would slow it down. I also wanted to make it boot from the ssd but I don't think that's possible if it is in the optical bay?

Comment: The location of the drive doesn't make any difference... the case of your computer has nothing to do with the performance of any component. It's just there to house all the different parts, and as long as they fit, they'll be fine. You can put both SSD and/or HDD in the bay from your optical drive. The only difference with the optical bay is that it doesn't have all the necessary mounts to screw your [HD/SS]D drive in. Then you connect the data and power cables to the drive and you're good to go.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the help. I did find out that the sata port for the optical drive caps the transfer rate at 3 gb. What I'll probably end up doing is moving the hdd to the optical drive and the ssd into the hdd port that supports 6 gb.

Comment: What part of "you can just swap the cables on the mobo" is not clear to you? :) Oh well, you'll see once you open the box.

Comment: So... Finally did it. It is very clear now. The mobo had 2 sata ports and a weird half port. The ODD was plugged into the first sata port, the HDD had one cable to the fan and the other cable to just the right part of the sata. I moved this cable to the left of the fan cable freeing up the sata port. I then plugged my ssd into the first sata port and finished. My system overview reports everything working normal, no crazy fan noise (like I've read about), and the negotiated speed for the SATA port (port for the new SSD), is 6 gb.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the Harddisk by an SSD in almost any iMac. I did it on my old 2009 iMac 24.

Like you mentioned, you can also remove the Optical Drive and add a second Harddisk (or your SSD). You have the choice - they are both connected via standard SATA cables (maybe check if they are both SATA-3 compatible for the maximum speed).

The best guide for that is https://www.ifixit.com, here you find detailed information how to open you iMac and how to replace the hdd or remove the optical drive.

[This is the guide to replace the harddisk of the iMac 2011](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+EMC+2429+Hard+Drive+Replacement/7555).

[This is the guide how to make a dual-harddisk for the iMac 2011](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+iMac+Intel+27-Inch+EMC+2429+Dual+Hard+Drive+Kit/7575)